# CKEDITOR: Some icons are not showing up in my toolbar

Tags: ckeditor

I 'd like  to ask this small but very important question i got: (I Downloaded CKeditor 4.3.2, and believe me i've been looking for this over the internet for ssooooooo long without any success.)

I've tried to show the 'Smiley' icon in my toolbar, but it doesn't show it, and that happens with some others like 'Save', 'Print', 'NewPage' for instance and i don't  know why. Also when i insert a link of a video isn't show either in order people watch it once is posted... Everything works just fine with the others but not with these i just mentioned! Please! thanks for reply!

PS: I've found in some forums that icons in these version 4.3.2 have change theirs names, u think that is the reason?

here is my code:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{   
uiColor: '#14B8C4',
config.toolbar = 'Full';

  `config.toolbar_Full =
[
{ name: 'document', items : [ 'Source','-', 'Save','NewPage','DocProps','Preview','Print','-','Templates', 'Emoticons' ] },//solo Source
{ name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo', 'clipboard' ] },//BIen
{ name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','SpellChecker', 'Scayt', 'TextColor' ] },//Solo SpellChecker
{ name: 'forms', items : [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', //nada
    'HiddenField' ] },
'/',
{ name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },//Todas
{ name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv', 'JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl' ] },//Todas hasta Bloquiote
{ name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] }, //Todas
{ name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule',"Smiley",'SpecialChar','PageBreak','Iframe' ] }, //Falta flash, smiley, ifame
'/',
{ name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ] }, 
{ name: 'colors', items : [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] }, //ninguno
{ name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-' ] }
];

//ToolBar groups configuration
                config.toolbarGroups = [
                { name: 'document', groups: ['mode', 'document', 'doctools']},
                { name: 'clipboard', groups: ['clipboard', 'undo']},
                { name: 'editing', groups: ['find', 'selection', 'spellchecker']},
                { name: 'forms'},
                '/',
                { name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup']},
                { name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi']},
                { name: 'links'},
                { name: 'insert'},
                '/',
                { name: 'styles'},
                { name: 'colors'},
                { name: 'tools'},
                { name: 'others'},
                ];
};
```

`

Comment: How you are configuring your toolbar? Posting some code will help.

Comment: I just posted my code from my ckeditor.js, hope it helps, bro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the solution which was very simple. But, before I tell you the solution I'll tell you the reason:

- CKEditor has been updated. So, some plugins' names have been changed, you're not going to find them with the same name as you used to.

Solution is: go to [Download CKEditor with plugins selected by you](http://ckeditor.com/download), and there you're going to find three different packages to download and below there's another one: "Or let me customize my CKEditor" click on it and "download & customize editor".

After that you'll be redirected to another page on which you'll see two columns, the left one shows you all the plugins that come with the package by default (you can also eliminate some plugins if you don't want them) and the right column shows you some plugins that can be added to the package().

Hope you find this solution helpful.

Comment: The CDN was failing to use the SAVE plugin for me. (The icon never appeared even though the empty space for it was functional.) To get it to function I had to take the step above. Of note, however, even though I chose the "Save" plugin - it didn't actually download despite that it supposedly would be included in the bundle. I had to still download the Save plugin separately.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the plugins installed to support those missing buttons?

I was seeing that in the CKeditor we've been using for a while now, all of the sudden, it lost some of it's toolbar buttons.

They were configured to be there, yet did not display.  Buttons like TextColor, the Justifieds, etc..

What our problem turned out to be was that we were missing the plugins for these buttons.  We must have switched from a compilation that included some plugins to the base code or something.